# What does file permission number (e.g.100644) mean?

Tags: git

Git tracks file permissions, I understand what `0644` means but what does the leading `10` mean in this example?

```
4 files changed, 201 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 my_file
```